# NGINX Configuraiton for Certbot/Letsencrypt

Tags: nginx, lets-encrypt, certbot

I am unable to get **certbot** up and running on my **NGINX/Ubuntu18.04** instance. I ran through the walkthrough at

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-apache-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-18-04

I opted to have **certbot** redirect and it updated my configuration file for my site.

My configuration files looks like this:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /var/www/punkmap.com/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name punkmap.com www.punkmap.com;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/punkmap.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/punkmap.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

The additions that **certbot** makes to my configuration file breaks my site. It is easy to fix by removing the lines of code that **certbot** added to my config file. However, I can find no information on the internet that shows how to correct the issue.

What should my site configuration look like?

Thanks!

Tyler

Comment: You could do a manual configuration.

Comment: Look at the Nginx error log and also check the configuration using `nginx -t`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have two `listen` directives in the same server block. Your best solution is to manually edit your nginx configuration to split into two server blocks. The non-ssl (port 80) block should redirect to the ssl (port 443) block. Something like this should work:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;

  server_name punkmap.com www.punkmap.com;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {

  root /var/www/punkmap.com/html;
  index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

  server_name punkmap.com www.punkmap.com;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }

  listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on;
  listen 443 ssl;
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/punkmap.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/punkmap.com/privkey.pem;
  include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
  ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
}
```

And then in the future, when you upgrade, make sure to pass the `--cert-only` parameter so that your configuration is not mucked with again. Notice that I deleted all of the *# managed by Certbot* comments, because after this, they will be managed by you.